# Error returning reference to a temporary value when implementing a trait for a type reference

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I am trying to implement a simple trait which returns a reference to some data (`GetData`).
For different reasons, I need to implement this trait for reference to my type (`&Base<T>`). I also would like to have a wrapper type that owns the base type and implements the trait.

The simplified example looks like this:

```rust
    // Trait
    trait GetData<T> {
      fn get_data(&self) -> &T;
    }
    
    // Base type
    struct Base<T> {
      pub data: T,
    }
    
    impl<T> GetData<T> for &Base<T> {
      fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        &self.data
      }
    }
    
    // Wrapper type owning a Base type
    struct Wrapper<T> {
      base: Base<T>,
      //...
    }
    
    impl<T> GetData<T> for &Wrapper<T> {
      fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        (&self.base).get_data()  // E0515: returns a value referencing data owned by the current function 
        //&self.base.data        // This works fine!
      }
    }
```

When implementing `get_data` for a `&Wrapper<T>` I get an error of returning a temporary value from my function. As I understand `&self.base` is borrowed by `GetData::get_data`. I am not sure how to resolve it though. All my attempts to add explicit lifetimes didn't work so far.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with this:

```rust
    impl<T> GetData<T> for &Base<T> {
      fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        &self.data
      }
    }
```

Now in all honesty I've no idea why you'd bother implementing only for `&Base` instead of just implementing for `Base`. But that's the cause of the issue because the lifetime of the Base and the lifetime of the self *are not the same* and your `self` is an `&&Base<T>`.

This means in:

```rust
      fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        (&self.base).get_data()  // E0515: returns a value referencing data owned by the current function 
        //&self.base.data        // This works fine!
      }
```

the lifetime of the result is that of `&self.base` which is purely local to the function, instead of being the expected lifetime of `self`.

If you

```rust
    impl<T> GetData<T> for Base<T> {
      fn get_data(&self) -> &T {
        &self.data
      }
    }
```

then everything works out of the box.

Can't help but think the entire thing smells of OO-thinking, a `GetData` trait stinks of Java/C# interface.

Comment: I feel that indeed I am doing things OO way and Rust resists :). I had to implement the trait for a reference because I wanted it to also return an associated type which is an iterator of the form `std::slice::Iter<'a, U>`. Will appreciate it if you can recommend anything to read about "Rust way".
But at least now I understand why it doesn't work. Thanks!